# Complexity of factorial number system

Tags: computational-complexity, symmetric-groups, number-systems

I implemented symmetric groups via factorial number system (or "factoriadic"): [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54000646/4540658) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54016517/4540658)

So I tried to calculate the complexity. Since the unit of complexity is bits, I calculated how many bits compose a number of factoriadic. Given that it has radix $N$, it has $\log 1 + \log 2 + \cdots + \log N = \log N!$ bits. We set this as $n$, and represent all complexities as a function of $n$. Is this the correct way to analyze time complexity?

Now given a complexity is $f(N)$, we need the inverse function of $\log N!$. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an easily expressed inverse.  You can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)
$$N! \approx N^Ne^{-N}\sqrt{2\pi N}\\
\log N! \approx (N +\frac 12)\log N -N+\frac 12\log(2\pi)$$
and do one dimensional root finding to get $N$ from $\log N!$  This uses natural logs rather than base $2$ logs, but it is a small correction.

Comment: Sorry for making confusions. I'm not familiar with LaTeX. I mean $\log N! \approx N \log N$.

Comment: That approximation ignores the $-N$ .  It maybe accurate enough for the purpose at hand.  For $N=50$ we have $\log(50!) \approx 148.48, 50\log (50)\approx 195.60$